# Code::Blocks for understanding C++ code it can't build

Tags: ide, codeblocks

Have a C++ source I probably can't build in Code::Blocks.  If I use it as an editor, would it be helpful in gaining understanding of the code?  (Like Intellisense).

How does it compare to **Visual Studio** in this respect?

How should I go about doing it?

Can it somehow utilize gdb information (When I run it in gdb, there is a lot of information available)

---

It is Linux gcc/Makefile based.

The main executable is in one directory, but there are many includes, libraries etc.
If I just included all sources I would get sources for other executables (with similar code).

### I expect to increase my understanding about where things are located over time.

Note 1: This is Linux, but I can easily edit on Windows. And I am trying to build under Cygwin.

Comment: [Code::Blocks works on Windows](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries). What about your C++ source won't build? You can choose many different compilers for it.

Comment: I think Code::Blocks doesn't understand Makefiles I think?  And also it doesn't know gdb.  Compiling the files in the main project should be possible.

Comment: It can. You can customize the built commands to use whatever script you like.

Comment: Code::Blocks lets you manage your own makefile. NetBeans will make you a makefile.

Comment: about "won't build" - I just think it would take a long time to set it up so that everything builds in the IDE native format or one it can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks sounds too light weight for your tastes. Try NetBeans. It has very good hinting tools, doesn't have the infamous copy+paste bug, Its easier to navigate files, and can deal with makefiles better then C::B. Additionally it has a nice interface for debugging, and an exceptional one for performance monitoring.

I would reccomend you install a linux distro through WUBI and forgo using Windows.

Comment: It seems to be better for gdb than Code::blocks?

Comment: Do you have any references to using NetBeans in this way? (As an editor, without necessarily being able to build)

Comment: What is the "infamous copy+paste bug"?

Comment: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13833.0 . It is fairly infamous because of the number of searches on how to fix it. This exists only in Linux and is in the version apt installs on Xubuntu. I haven't found any way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used NetBeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, and CodeLite. I don't normally write software under Windows anymore, but when I did CodeLite was the most elegant one I found. Debugging was a snap (mingw + GDB), all the meta information about your project is stored in an sqlite db (which I think is a great design), and it supports makefiles.

I think NetBeans would work great as well, but definitely give CodeLite a shot.

http://www.codelite.org/

Comment: Are you thinking of my situation here (Editing code you perhaps can not build)

Comment: As far as editing code you cannot build, well, you just need an editor that treats the files as a big bag of indexable items that you can syntax highlight and code complete on, right? CodeLite will do this, Netbeans will do this, and Eclipse. Visual Studio will to an extent, as well. I don't know why you cannot build it - what build system does it use? Makefiles? Scons? Cmake?